# codeigniter Registration

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I register , redirected in to the another page  .  But, I refreshed that page, it goes to the `index page.This is the error`. Please provide solution for this problem.

Controller

```
    public function register()
    {

        $this->load->view('index');
    }
    public function do_register()
    {

      $this->load->library('form_validation');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('uname', 'Username', 'required|min_length[4]|max_length[15]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('mail', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'Password', 'required|min_length[4]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('titleimg','Title','required|min_length[4]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('descrip', 'Description', 'required|min_length[4]');
    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
         $data=$this->data;
        $data['error']= '' ;
        $this->load->view('index',$data); 

      }
    else
    {  
       $path = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $imgext=strtolower(strrchr($path,'.'));
        $imgname= $this->generateRandomString().$imgext;
       /* echo "imgname".$imgname;
       die();*/  
       if($path!='')
       {  
       $im= $this->config->item('base_url').'/uploads'.'/'.$imgname;
       $x=$this->do_upload($imgname);

 $data['img']=$im;

 if ($x['error']=='')
   {
   $this->user_model->register_user($data['img']);
   $this->load->view('register_view');
   }
   else
   {
    $data['error']=  $x['error'] ;
    $this->load->view('index',$data);
   }
   }
    }
    }

 function generateRandomString()
  {
     $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
     $randomString = '';
     for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
         $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
     }
     return $randomString;
  } 

        function do_upload($img)
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        //$config['max_size'] = '2048000';
        //$config['max_size'] = '1048576 ';
        $config['max_size'] = '1024 ';

        $config['file_name'] = $img;   


        $this->load->library('upload',$config);
        //$this->upload->data('image');
        //print_r("Hello->". $config['upload_path']);
   //die();
//print_r("Hello12345->".$this->upload->do_upload('image'));
 // die();




        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('image'))

        {//echo"333333".$this->upload->do_upload('image');
        //die();
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $data['error']=$error;
            return $data;
            //return $error;    
        }
        else
        {
            //print_r("Hell11o->".$this->upload->data());
         // die(); 

            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            //$this->load->view('register_view',$data);

              $data['error']='';
             return $data;
        }
        return;
    }
```

View:

```
<button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reg-modal">Register </button>
  <!-- Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="reg-modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h2>Register</h2>

      <form   action="<?=site_url('home/do_register')?>"   method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return validate();">
        <div>
          <label> Username&nbsp;</label>
          <?php echo form_error('uname'); ?>
          <input type="text"  name="uname" placeholder="Enter the username here" required   value="<?php echo set_value('uname'); ?>" />
        </div>


        <div>
          <label> Email &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
          <?php echo form_error('mail'); ?>
          <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Email" required   value="<?php echo set_value('mail'); ?>" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label> Password&nbsp; </label>
          <?php echo form_error('pass')?>
          <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Your Password" required   value="<?php echo set_value('pass'); ?>" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Title  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
          <?php echo form_error('titleimg')?>
          <input type="text" name="titleimg" placeholder="Image Title" required value="<?php echo set_value('titleimg');?>"/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label> Upload image </label>
        <?php echo form_error('image')?>
          <input type="file"  class="upload" name="image" id="file" required value="<?php echo set_value('image'); ?>" />
          <span id="file_error"></span> 
          <script type="text/javascript">
                       $(document).on('change','.upload',function(){
      files = this.files;
      size = files[0].size;
      //max size 50kb => 50*1000

      if( size > 1000141){
         alert('Please upload less than 1mb file');
         return false;
      }
      return true;
});
</script> 
        </div>
        <div>
          <label> Description</label>
          <?php echo form_error('descrip')?>
          <input type="text"  name="descrip" cols="30" rows="4" value="<?php echo set_value('descrip'); ?>" / >
        </div>
         <input type="submit" name="btn-reg" value="  Register   " />
        <!--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Register</button>-->
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div> <!-- Modal--->
```

After the successful registration  , when I refresh the page it goes to the index page.

Comment: can you paste `<form>` html code please?

Comment: Yes  i set action for the form

Comment: after success registration use redirect and create new function to call view

Comment: user1048123 How can i use redirect and create new function to call view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($x['error']=='')
   {
   $this->user_model->register_user($data['img']);
   $this->load->view('register_view');
   }
```

change this to

```
if ($x['error']=='')
   {
   $this->user_model->register_user($data['img']);
   redirect('home/registersuccess');
   }
```

Write new function

```
function registersuccess(){
    $this->load->view('register_view');
}
```